# How to apply the same white point to multiple clips of the same take?

Tags: editing, final-cut-pro-x

I shot one take with a camera that could not set white balance. I imported it into Final Cut Pro and set the white balance from a white point. I then cut the take into multiple slices and shuffled them around. I tried removing the white balance adjustment and then Final Cut Pro hung on me. How can I apply the same color correction to all slices of the same take?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the corrections to one slice as an effect preset and apply the preset to all other clips with [directions from Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/final-cut-pro/verbbd35f70/mac):

> You apply a color correction preset as you would apply any other clip effect from the Effects browser.